# Uniqueness of stationary distributions in continuous time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, solution-verification, markov-process, stationary-processes

**Question**

Consider a Markov process $\{X(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ with state space $$S = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$$ and generator matrix
$$Q =
\begin{pmatrix}
-q_0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & -q_1 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 4 & -q_2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -q_3
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Find a stationary distribution $\pi_R$ of the embedded chain. Is $\pi_R$ unique? Explain your reasoning.

**My working**

In earlier parts of this problem, I have determined a stationary distribution associated with $Q$ to be $$\pi_Q = \left(\frac 1 5, \frac 1 5, \frac 1 5, \frac 2 5\right).$$ I have also determined the transition matrix of the embedded chain to be
$$R =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac 1 3 & 0 & \frac 2 3 & 0\\
0 & \frac 2 3 & 0 & \frac 1 3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
so that $$\pi_R = \left(\frac 1 8, \frac 3 8, \frac 3 8, \frac 1 8\right).$$

---

However, I am unsure whether $\pi_R$ is unique and why. I am thinking that $\pi_R$ is indeed unique and in particular, $\pi_R$ and $\pi_Q$ are related in some way. Would I be correct? Any advice will be greatly appreciated :)